Download a File using HTTP from Azure Data Factory and storing it on File Storage
I am new to Azure Data Factory, I have followed tutorial online and learnt how to download data from api to ADF and storing the zip file. However when I run the pipeline I'm getting these error
ErrorCode=HttpRequestFailedWithClientError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Http request failed with client error, status code 400 BadRequest, please check your activity settings. If you configured a baseUrl that includes path, please make sure it ends with '/'.
Request URL: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxAPI.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.,Source=System,'

I tried running the api base url on postman and it is running properly.
enter image description here

If the API is working properly in Postman but not in ADF, it is possible that the issue is related to the network configuration or authentication settings in ADF. Solution is to use a self-hosted integration runtime to access the API from ADF. This would allow you to run the pipeline on a machine that has access to the API and can authenticate properly.
Below are the high-level steps to use a self-hosted integration runtime to access the API from ADF:

Install the self-hosted integration runtime on a machine that has access to the API and can authenticate properly.
Create an HTTP linked service in ADF that points to the API endpoint.
Configure the linked service to use the self-hosted integration runtime instead of the auto-resolved integration runtime.
Use the linked service in your pipeline to access the API and transfer data between the API and the cloud-based services.


By using a self-hosted integration runtime, you can ensure that the pipeline is running on a machine that has the necessary network configuration and authentication settings to access the API. This should help resolve any issues related to network connectivity or authentication that might be causing the pipeline to fail.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory
